# Selenium giving error 111 after running a loop in python3 inside WSL (Debian for WSL, WSL2)

Tags: python, selenium, debian, windows-subsystem-for-linux, urllib3

Yes, I know the <s>main</s> general reason for this error. Im just unable to understand why Im getting it.

The Problem:
I made a script in python which uses selenium and bs4 to **scrape** a piece of information from websites in a list. When I put it in a loop, it doesn't show any urllib3 Error 111 but after the script stops or after forcedly stopping the loop when I try anything with browser.get(#anysite), it throws this error. If I do del browser and remake it then the error is nowhere to be found.

The error

> raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
> urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1',
> port=51841): Max retries exceeded with url:
> /session/50c8eae33ca98c4ceedb4988d72d27cd/url (Caused by
> NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at
> 0x7f3d42858908>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111]
> Connection refused',))

The platform Im running the script is Debian for wsl<<wsl2<<windows 10 2004

As for the script, it contains sensitive info so Im unable to show it. If the script is really needed, then I will try to replicate this error in another site. I hope I can understand as to the real reason Im getting this error.

PS: This is my first question after haunting stackoverflow for some years. As I almost always found my answers here I hadn't a need to do this in past.

Edit:
This piece of code may possibly be able to replicate the error.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()  
chromeOptions.add_argument("--headless") 
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chromeOptions) 
c=1
while c==1:
    browser.get("http://users.ox.ac.uk/~csrob/ecdla/")
    x=1
    while x==1:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "html.parser")
        y=soup.find("h2")
        if not y.find("This")==-1:
            x=0
            print("loaded")
```

After letting it run for a bit(say 2-5 min) Interrupt the code with Ctrl+C and then when browser.get(#anysite) is done urllib3 Error 111 appears.

So far what I've tried,

1)Searching for error on google, came across multiple sites with info on when error 111 occurs {when the server refuses(not applicable in my case), occurs when shifting from http to https(not applicable in my case), happened in old versions of urllib3}

2)Editing value of total to 0 in line 439 of /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py Gives some kind of recursive error.

3)Tried the same code in Ubuntu for wsl(in version 18.04 and 20.04), Fedora Remix for wsl both gave same error

4)Turning off Windows Defender Firewall

Edit2:
I think I found out why I was getting this error. Seems like sometimes Chrome gets stuck/hang during the process and is unable to get out of it and the only way is to close and open another instance of it. I found this out when running the script on windows normally(without WSL or headerless option). Still Im unable to figure out why this doesn't happen when in loop.

Comment: Welcome to SO! There is a better chance that you will get a high quality answer if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I can add the code Im using since i found that nothing sensitive will be revealed but it won't be reproducible since appropriate permissions will be required. I understand without ppl being able to reproduce this error I wont get right answers so I will try to reproduce this error on some other site. Meanwhile, would a video on it help, if yes should I upload it in youtube? Or should I delete this question until I am able to provide ppl a reproducible example? or Should I just add on my code which is unreproducible?

Comment: Yes. A reproducible example is the gold standard. But if you can provide relevant code that will help a lot. It is astonishing what the SO community can answer. :)

Comment: Updated, hope this addition makes the query more complete. If it is still missing something please tell me. My thanks to all ppl who see my question and all the awesome ppl who are a part of this community, This site has really helped me quite a few times past few years.